# How webscokets connect to the correct child process inside a cluster?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, pm2, ws

I am trying to figure out how websockets work inside a Nodejs/PM2 cluster.

I have just conducted an experiment by laucnhing 4 child processes using PM2, then from client I sent multiple webocket messages to all 4 socket servers (1 ws server running within each child process). One thing I didn't expect was that Node was able to figure out what process the socket belongs to, therefor every message sent by the client was console logged by the correct child process.

So is this behavior managed by Nodejs internally by the cluster module? It also seems like this is a new feature since Node 12? I might be wrong...

Code reference (ws module uses tsl): https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/websocket.js#L663

**P.S:** Before writing an answer, please check the comments I wrote to others...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    webSocket=function(server) {

    var io = require('socket.io')(server,{ transports: ['websocket', 'polling'] });
    var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
    var pub = require('redis').createClient(6379,'localhost');
    var sub = require('redis').createClient(6379,'localhost');
    io.adapter(redis({pubClient: pub, subClient: sub}));

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('Connection Establish!!!!!');
    )}
};


app.JS
https.createServer(options, app).listen(httpsAddress, function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + config.get('PORT'));
    webSocket(this)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you need a centralised message broker. The N processes would have N non shared memory/config/storage. The most popular choice is `redis`.
Socket.io does this out of the box with `redis-adapter`.

So, 
1) Install redis
2) Install the redis adapter from [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis)

After that you can follow @pritamjana's code.

From the adapter doc:

> By running socket.io with the socket.io-redis adapter you can run
>   multiple socket.io instances in different processes or servers that
>   can all broadcast and emit events to and from each other.

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);
const redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redisAdapter({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));

// So any of the following commands:

io.emit('hello', 'to all clients');
io.to('room42').emit('hello', "to all clients in 'room42' room");

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.broadcast.emit('hello', 'to all clients except sender');
  socket.to('room42').emit('hello', "to all clients in 'room42' room except sender");
});
```

Comment: For this code to work in a cluster, the servers still needs to keep track of the connections for each N process. As stated in my experiment, this is exactly what happens, my question is how? Thank you anyway :)

Comment: What do you mean in your question you sent to ` all 4 socket servers`. So why woudn't it console log the correct one? 
Maybe add the code in your question so that we can see what are you trying to tell.

Comment: So client (frontend app) should emit message directly to message broker instead to backend? Or it should send via normal http request to backend which send message to message broker?